# Not that urgent

Tags: meaning, grammar, grammaticality, expressions, formality

Is it grammatically correct to say “ not that urgent” as a reply to ( I will call you now if it’s urgent) for something not urgent

Comment: Perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is grammatically correct. More formally, use "It's not *too* urgent". Note that "noncritical" and "nonurgent" (US English only) are also words in themselves, so that's an alternative too.